# Python - get the last element of each list in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

My question is quite simple, I have a list of lists :

```
my_list = [['a1','b1'],['a2','b2'],['a3','b3','c3'],['a4','b4','c4','d4','e4']]
```

How can I get easily the the last element of each list i.e. :

```
[ 'b1' , 'b2' , 'c3' , 'e4' ]
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 14):

You can get the last element of each element with the index `-1` and just do it for all the sub lists.

```
print [item[-1] for item in my_list]
# ['b1', 'b2', 'c3', 'e4']
```

If you are looking for idiomatic way, then you can do

```
import operator
get_last_item = operator.itemgetter(-1)
print map(get_last_item, my_list)
# ['b1', 'b2', 'c3', 'e4']
print [get_last_item(sub_list) for sub_list in my_list]
# ['b1', 'b2', 'c3', 'e4']
```

If you are using Python 3.x, then you can do this also

```
print([last for *_, last in my_list])
# ['b1', 'b2', 'c3', 'e4']
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative with `map`:

```
last_items = map(lambda x: x[-1], my_list)
```

or:

```
from operator import itemgetter
print map(itemgetter(-1), my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try ,

Here is [demo](http://codepad.org/SyuS0ZcQ).

```
>>> [i.pop() for i in my_list]
['b1', 'b2', 'c3', 'e4']
```

**OR**

```
>>> my_list = [['a1','b1'],['a2','b2'],['a3','b3','c3'],['a4','b4','c4','d4','e4']]
>>> [i[-1] for i in my_list]
['b1', 'b2', 'c3', 'e4']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
my_list = [['a1','b1'],['a2','b2'],['a3','b3','c3'],['a4','b4','c4','d4','e4']]
print(my_list)

for each_list in my_list:
    last_element = each_list[-1]
    print(last_element)
```

[Code tested successfully to arrive at the expected result - In the Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfKgP.png)

Answer (score 0):

See the below answer,

```
my_list = [['a1','b1'],['a2','b2'],['a3','b3','c3'],['a4','b4','c4','d4','e4']]

new_list = []
for sub_list in my_list:
    new_list.append(sub_list[-1])

print(new_list) # o/p: [ 'b1' , 'b2' , 'c3' , 'e4' ]
```

I hope it helps you to find the answer.